# Django NOT EXISTS query

Tags: sql, django

I don't know how to do **a not exists query** in Django views.

My query is:

```
select * from states
where date <= #../././#
  and not exists (select * from states as states2
                  where states2.id > states.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django you don't use actual SQL, the framework provides you with a simple object notation.

In your case, you could simply do this check:

```
    //SELECT from db to MyObjectsList
    MyObjectsList = MyObject.objects.filter(date = 8/04/2015)

    if not MyObjectsList: //check if list is empty (in a pythonic way)
        itemDoesntExist()
```

Where `itemDoesntExist()` will be another query that will check for alternatives (in your case).

Check out [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/) for details on how to retrieve objects from your database with Django.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Ali, but this method it's too slow